# java -cp/javac doesn't work in cmd prompt

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I am trying to run mo program by cmd :

- first i try to compile my Main.java by "javac Main.java", after that i have no msg in cmd
- second i run "java -cp Main"(Main.class with byte code), after that i have no output in cmd
  I tryed reinstall my JDK, but it doesn't help. also when i run "java -version" in cmd i have no output. and no msg.I has set my JAVA_HOME path into JDK dir and set him into my PATH "%JAVA_HOME\bin". what i cant do wrong? Pls help

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Run `java Main`?

Comment: `-cp` is for classpath

Comment: also tried without -cp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path environment variable for java is not set correctly. You could try to run the command `where java` and most likely it will return a path that is not correct (or nothing).
Find the correct path where your JDK is installed and run this command to add it to the path vars in cmd:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\here\
```

An example for my system and path would be:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin
```

After setting this path variable, close and reopen your cmd window and try running `java -version` again.
If it still doesn't show anything then you have to manually change your path variables and remove the old path.

Comment: i manually remove my path to jdk. and set it again. but it doesn't work, i put new screen in post

Comment: Remove all of them and set only one as your java path.

Comment: Many thanks, it help out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have correctly set the path to the directory in which you have your java installed. For instance mine is settled in D:\Program files\java\jdk-11.0.2

Subsequently I set JAVA_HOME as [image: JAVA_HOME]

Then you open **path** variable and new entry as following:
[image: path variable]

Then save all changes. Close all running cmd, start it again and then retry java -version